# Getting URL prefix in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, redirect

I have an app that is hosted on the test server on the url `192.168.42.42/foo-app`. Locally, it works on `localhost:9000`. I also have a route `/docs/swagger-ui` that must redirect to `docs/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/docs/swagger`. Here is a routes file:

```
GET     /docs/swagger               controllers.Assets.at(path = "/public", file = "swagger.json")
GET     /docs/swagger-ui            foo.app.controller.ApplicationController.swaggerUI
GET     /docs/swagger-ui/*file      controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/lib/swagger-ui", file: String)
```

And here is my `ApplicationController`:

```
package foo.app.controller

import play.api.mvc.{AbstractController, ControllerComponents}

class ApplicationController(cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) {

  def swaggerUI = Action { implicit request =>
    val pathPrefix = extractPathPrefix(request.path)
    Redirect(s"$pathPrefix/docs/swagger-ui/index.html?url=$pathPrefix/docs/swagger")
  }

  private def extractPathPrefix(path: String) = {
    path.split("/")
      .toList
      .filterNot(_.isEmpty)
      .headOption
      .filterNot(_ == "docs")
      .map(s => s"/$s")
      .getOrElse("")
  } 
}
```

Everything work perfect locally, but on test server redirection goes to `192.168.42.42/docs/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/docs/swagger` while I need it to go to `192.168.42.42/foo-app/docs/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/foo-app/docs/swagger`
So it seems that `/foo-app` is eliminated somehow. Can anyone help me understand what's wrong?

Comment: You could host the website on `192.168.42.42`, then look into different run modes in Play - for example in Production mode, you could go through another Routes file which prepends `/foo-app` to the URL paths (look into multiple Routes files). I think that Play is assuming that `/foo-app` is a part of the `192......` part and ignoring it, as it is not seeing it as part of `request.path`.

Comment: That's just a guess though. I would be interested to see what `request.path` prints out when run on a server vs on your local machine.